# Image Showing through Spry Menu Bar after hover over

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, spry

I have the menu working correct on IE with z-indexs but can't get the same results with chrome and firefox.  If you go to www.rsd17.org/test/test/untitled1.shtml and on the top spry menu bar hover over students.  Then mouse down to any of the items you will see the corner of the picture go through the menu.  This is not the case in IE.  Anyone know which element I need to change in my css to correct this issue?  Let me know if you guys need to see my CSS to help out.

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: not sure how easy it would be to fiddle since I have several SSIs per page.  I can try and make a fiddle on Monday if no one else can give me suggetions.

Comment: Just use the HTML output in your fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gvkyr/ here is the best I could do.  check out www.rsd17.org/test/test/untitled1.shtml for the live version.  I think it has to do something with position of left column.  I somewhat got it to do what I wanted, with making left column absolute and the two divs inside relative, but then the right column I have didn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed the issue by adding in relative position to the menu and submenu, and made the whole bar position absolute.  Not sure if this is the correct way to do this, but this is how I fixed my issue.